# Nextjs13 experimental app directory with next auth not working/ giving a session?

Tags: next.js, next-auth, next.js13

I am using next.js auth 4.

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcAPy.png)

As you can see here is my file structure. I am using next.js's experimental app folder component. I was told to not use pages for this but I ran into a problem with this. This code is straight out of the next.js box but in next auth it says I need to wrap my entire app in a session provider. I here on stack to use the layouts file for it. But in this advice I don't have a session to give my session provider!

see:
rootlayout.jsx

```js
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  
  return (
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
      <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <title>Testing code</title>
    </head>
    <body className={inter.className}>
      <Providers>
        {children}
      </Providers>
    </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

provider.jsx

```js
'use client'
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"



const Providers = ({children}) => {
    return ( 
        <>
            <SessionProvider>
                {children}
            </SessionProvider>
        </>
     );
}
 
export default Providers;
```

The session provider doesn't get a session because of the root layout.

Before the app.jsx would give it a session.

If I add an pages folder it might interfere with the project but how can I  fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I see some issues in the above code.

1. Folder structure issue
   It should be something like

> ```
> app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js
> ```

**[...nextauth]** - is a folder used by nextjs for dynamic routing 
**example** - localhost:3000/api/auth/callback

For refrence - https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/example


2. **provider.jsx**

```js
'use client';

import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';

const Provider = ({ children, session }) => {
    return <SessionProvider session={session}>{children}</SessionProvider>;
};

export default Provider;
```

3. In folder structure shared above its mentioned layout.jsx and page.jsx which is correct but in question you mentioned rootLayout.jsx which is incorrect. I don't understand which one you are using but the correct way to do it is by using
   **layout.jsx**

```js
export const metadata = {
    title: 'Promptopia',
    description: 'Dsicover & Share AI Prompts',
};

const RootLayout = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body>
                <Provider> 
                    {children}
                </Provider>
            </body>
        </html>
    );
};

export default RootLayout;
```

Note: Please import provider used in layout.jsx
You dont have to send session manually from rootLayout, Nextjs will take care of that automatically

Comment: How would the above code change if im using typescript ? I get an error because Provider needs a "session" argument but I have no session to pass to it in the layout file.